# Update firebase messaging using python and django

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase Admin SDK in Python.

```
//import sdk

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging


//saved json credentials from google in a private storage
json_file = settings.PRIVATE_STORAGE_JSON_FIREBASE + "/" + "firebase_json/" + "firebase_json.json"
cred = credentials.Certificate(json_file)

//initialize 

app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(credentials, name="app")

//sent push message

def send_message(title, msg, registration_token):

    message = messaging.`MulticastMessage`(
        notification=messaging.Notification(
        title=title,
        body=msg),
        tokens=registration_token

        )
```

Ok so far so good, this is working fine. However i received an email from google "Your recent usage of impacted APIs/features: `Admin SDK(batch send API)`". I should resolve it "Send messages via the HTTP v1 API, which has been optimized for fanout performance".

Questions:

1. As of my understanding iam using the `HTTPV1`, or am i not right?
2. Now i am aware that in my message sending i use multicast (this is `batch sending`, to multiple users). I don't need the batch sending here, i only have to sent to one user/token. If i change the sending function, would this be enough to resolve google's requirements?

```
message = messaging.Message( // here the change (only sent to one token, instead of batch)
    notification=messaging.Notification(
      title=title,
      body=msg),
    tokens=registration_token
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing research the modifications are:
-updating to the latets admin sdk and update the code.

```
message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
    notification=messaging.Notification(
    title=title,
    body=msg),
    tokens=registration_token

    )

response = messaging.send_each_for_multicast(message, app=firebase_admin.get_app("app"))
```